# Wo kommt der Ausdruck "Puschen" her?

Tags: etymology, regional

Fast nur in Norddeutschland höre ich von *"Puschen"* im Zusammenhang mit Hausschuhen, die wir hier im Süden *"[Pantoffeln](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Pantoffel)"* nennen. Wir kennen aber schon auch den Ausdruck:

> *nicht in die **Puschen** kommen*

wenn jemand aus einer Ruhephase nicht rasch genug mit der Arbeit beginnt. Auch den Ausdruck

> *"Boah, der hat aber dicke **Puschen** dran"*

für ein Auto mit extrabreiten Reifen habe ich schon gehört.

Woher stammt dieser ganz nette Begriff *"Puschen"*; und warum wird er nur in Norddeutschland für *Pantoffeln* benutzt?

Comment: Und: Wird es mit `ʊ` gesprochen (kurzes u, wie in *und*) oder mit `u` (langes u, wie in *Stuhl*)? Ich habe schon beides gehört.

Comment: Ich habe das dumpfe Gefühl, dass in dem ngram-Graphen auch die eingedeutschte Version des englischen Worts "to push" oder "etwas pushen" (= etw. voranbringen, bewerben, ...) mit drin steckt. Ich weiß nicht, inwieweit Großschreibung eine Rolle bei Google ngram spielt, aber es kann sein dass bei einem recht seltenen Wort dann so Konstruktionen wie "Das aggresive Pushen/Puschen einzelner Künstler wird zunehmend zum Normalfall..." auf einmal das Ergebnis verfälschen.

Comment: @0x6d64: NGrams beachtet Groß-/Kleinschreibung und führt auch keine von den sonstigen bei Google-Suchen üblichen Korrekturen durch ([Beispiel](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Puschen%2Cpuschen&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=8&smoothing=3)).

Comment: Nachtrag: Ich hab mal die Worte pushen, Pushen und Puschen verglichen und es scheint da einen Zusammenhang zu geben, indem "Puschen" ungefähr zu dem Zeitpunkt abhebt, als auch die anderen Varianten häufiger werden: http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Pushen%2Cpushen%2CPuschen&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=8&smoothing=3

Comment: Außerdem gibt es noch das Verb "puschen", das offenbar umgangssprachlich in einigen Gegenden für "pinkeln" verwendet wird, evtl. nur Kindern gegenüber.

Comment: @fzwo Die norddeutschen Pantoffeln werden mit langem u gesprochen. Mit kurzem u ist das das eingedeutschte englische Verb *to push*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Der Begriff kommt wohl ursprünglich aus dem Persischen und bedeutet "Fußbekleidung".

Es gibt ähnlich klingende Nebenformen wie "[Pampusche](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Pampusche)". Daraus dürfte sich die verkürzte Form "Pusche" gebildet haben.

"Pampusche" wiederum hat die Nebenform "[Babusche](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Babusche)", was vom Französischen "[babouche](http://dict.leo.org/frde?lp=frde&search=babouche)" kommt. Laut Wiktionary hat sich diese Form über das Arabische aus dem Persischen entwickelt.

Es könnte sein, daß der Ausdruck im Norden als Definitionsabgrenzung zum Pantoffel verwendet wird. "Pantoffel" kenne ich nur als hinten offene Schuhe, Puschen als hinten geschlossene. Das ist aber nur Spekulation.

**Ergänzung:** Zu fzwos Frage: Wird "Puschen" mit kurzem oder langem u gesprochen (siehe Kommentar zur Frage oben):

Dies wird sehr von der Mundart abhängen, ganz speziell in diesem Fall, da es sich um einen regionalen Begriff handelt und nicht um einen der Hochsprache.

**Was für ein kurzes u spricht (wie in "Busch"):**

Zum einen verwendet Linguatec diese Aussprache (auf das Lautsprechersymbol in [diesem Link](http://dict.leo.org/frde?lp=frde&search=Puschen) klicken). Zum anderen könnte man von der Wortherkunft auf diese Aussprache schließen. Das Französische "[babouche](http://dict.leo.org/frde?lp=frde&p=ziiQA&search=babouche&trestr=0x8001)" wird mit kurzem u gesprochen.

**Was für ein langes u spricht (wie in "Dusche"):**

Hierfür spricht die ähnliche Schreibweise von "[Dusche](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Dusche)" und "[Pusche](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Puschen)". Sie läßt vermuten, daß die Wörter gleich ausgesprochen werden. Laut Wiktionary ist das auch der Fall.

Allerdings ist es laut Wiktionary möglich die Nebenform "[Babusche](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Babusche)" sowohl mit kurzem, als auch mit langem u auszusprechen.

Daraus schließe ich: So aussprechen wie es einem am besten gefällt.

Comment: In Norddeutschland wird es mit langem U ausgesprochen, wenigstens habe ich es niemals anders gehört. Andererseits wird es hier mitunter auch für Pantoffeln (also hinten geschlossene Hausschuhe) verwendet, jener Begriff ist hier oben jedoch eher unüblich. Die Herkunft finde ich aber doch recht interessant.

Answer (score 1):

Das Substantiv *Puschen* ist der *Hausschuh*.

> Hier drinnen werden nur Hauspuschen getragen.

Pantoffeln sind sowas wie Holzpantinen oder Holzschuhe bei uns im Norden. Bei der Aussprache gilt bei uns Fischköppen generell: Alle Vokale werden langgezogen. Wird *puschen* kleingeschrieben, heißt es *pinkeln*.

> Ich geh mal fix puschen.

Comment: Wenn ein Puschen ein Hausschuh ist, ist denn ein Hauspuschen ein Haushausschuh?

Answer (score 0):

Es gibt für Puschen noch eine andere Bedeutung im Sinne von „Ich muss puschen“ (*urinieren* oder umgangssprachlich *pinkeln*). Beide Begriffe sind mir, aus Berlin stammend, geläufig.