# Where is the origin of verb "puschen"?

Tags: etymology

Is it just a nowadays English adaptation of the verb *to push* ?

Comment: It would be good if you could add the meaning of the verb or an example. Also note that if you ask in English, many people will assume that your English is better than your German, which will influence the kind of answers that they give you. This may or may not be what you want.

Comment: Also see https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3153/wo-kommt-der-ausdruck-puschen-her

Answer (score 3, accepted):

German has two homonym verbs *puschen*:

### 1. puschen = to pee

There is an old and almost forgotten German verb *puschen* that means *to pee* (*to urinate*). It is very rare, and as already said, old and almost forgotten, and it's only alive in a few regions as part of colloquial speech (sorry, don't know which regions).

### 2. puschen = tu push

This is a relatively new and well known loanword, derived from the also very well known foreign word *pushen* which is a copy of the English verb *to push*, which itself is a French loanword (*pousser*) with a latin root (pulsāre).

Comment: "which is a copy of the English verb to push" - maybe syntactically, but certainly not semantically. There certainly are meanings of *to push* for which *puschenS would not be used.

Comment: Nicht zu vergessen das äußerlich sehr ähnliche Substantiv "der Puschen" (Hausschuh aus weichem Stoff). Wobei von der Aussprache her hier das u bei vielen Sprechern etwas länger sein wird als in *pushen* oder *puschen*.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Mir ist das Substantiv »der Puschen« bereits gestern bei der Recherche aufgefallen, davor kannte ich es nicht. Es wird in Österreich nicht verwendet, stattdessen werden Hausschuhe in Österreich als »Patschen« (mit geschlossener Ferse) oder »Schlapfen« (wenn die Ferse frei ist) bezeichnet. (»Patschen« ist auch die Bezeichnung für einen Fahrzeugreifen, insbesondere (aber nicht nur) wenn der Reifen wegen eines Lochs die Luft nicht halten kann.)

Comment: Bedeutung 1. wird auch heute noch in weiten Teilen Ostdeutschlands häufig verwendet und dürfte von *puschern* abgeleitet sein.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Das kenne als "pieschern". Vgl. https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/pieschern

Answer (score 2):

In Addition to JANKA
The verb "puschen" does exist in German, is not forgotten and has nothing to do with the modern German meaning (20th century, "to push something or someone").

It is used colloquially (at least) in the Berlin-Brandenburg area to describe urinating. As far as I know, it is used to describe a pet (dog, cat) peeing somewhere (often in an inappropriate place) or a small child having to pee somewhere of necessity. It is not used to describe a man peeing.

Answer (score -2):

The verb *puschen* does not exist in German. Do you mean the verb **pushen**? That's a 100% cognate of English **to push**, along with the slightly sharper pronounciation of *sh* in contrast to *sch*. It has been taken from English not before 40 years ago, I think.

Or do you mean the noun *Puschen* (pronounced with a long u)? That means *house slippers* and is mostly used in the phrase *Komm in die Puschen!* (Hurry up!), and as a synonym for shoes in general.

Or do you mean the verb *pfuschen?* That means *to botch* and is pretty easy to distiguish from *pushen* by the *explosive f == pf* sound on the beginning.

Comment: Not a cognate, a loan word.

Comment: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/puschen

Comment: Ehrlich gesagt kenn ich niemanden, der pushen mit sch schreibt. Braucht man vermutlich fehlende Englischkenntnisse dazu.

Comment: Auch im Duden stehts: [puschen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/puschen)

Comment: Wiktionary: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/puschen Duden: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/puschen DWDS: https://www.dwds.de/wb/puschen

Comment: Liebe Janka, *puschern*, oder etwas seltener *puschen*, ist mir das in Ostdeutschland geläufigste Verb überhaupt, mit dem man umgangssprachlich ausdrückt, dass man mal urinieren muss. Ich selbst verwende es andauernd, meine Familie, Bekannte, sogar enge Kollegen verwenden es. Zu behaupten, das Verb gäbe es gar nicht, finde ich daher aberwitzig!